# How to debug or check console on iPad for Phonegap application?

Tags: ipad, cordova

I'm having an odd issue.  I've developed a Phonegap application.  I can run it fine on the iOS Simulator on the Mac.  If I run it on an iPad using Xcode's "Run on iOS Device" mode, it runs fine.  However, when I generate an .ipa file for deployment and install it on the iPad, it has some problem.  It runs, but looks like it's encountering an error somewhere.

So my question is; is there any way to be able to try to look at the console messages so I can see where the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you connected it to your mac and checked the devices's console in the organiser?

Comment: I did not, but that did the trick!  If you post this as a reply, I'll be glad to flag it as the correct answer for you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the console in the organizer for your device to find any logged messages.

Answer (score 0):

I always debug my Phonegap iOS apps using the Safari console [(example)](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html)

Using Safari inspector you can edit CSS, debug Javascript and see the logs.